# Fully or partially Decrypting Data with Multiple keys

Tags: encryption

Is there any good paper or research carried out till now that a data is encrypted by a single key or onwer(user) and their are 2 or more decryption keys. One key can decrypt the entire data. Other keys decrypt partial data or a portion of data. A person having no key cannot decrypt the data but those having keys can fully or partially decrypt data based on the keys.

Comment: Are you sure you actually need a special algorithm for this? You could just encrypt different parts with different keys and give persons subsets of those.

Comment: It depends what you mean by a "portion" of data. Many works have addressed issues which seem related to this question. The closest I can think of is the [BCP cryptosystem](http://www.di.ens.fr/users/pointche/Documents/Papers/2003_asiacryptB.pdf). Each player can generate his own pair private/public key; the secret key of a player allows him to decrypt ciphertexts encrypted with his public key. Additionally, a master secret key can decrypt all the ciphertexts, whatever the public key used. (Other related and more powerful primitives are identity based and attribute based encryption).

Answer (score 1):

[Functional encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_encryption) might fit your description; as far as I know it's still far from practical though.